# Run PHPunit laravel error on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, phpunit, ubuntu-16.04, laravel-5.5

I encountered an error when I run phpunit laravel 5.5
This error is only in ubuntu 16.04, when I run phpunit in windows, it runs successfully.

Anyone can help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure you are running valid PhpUnit. Run it like this:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

You should make sure you are running PhpUnit installed in vendor directory in current Laravel installation and not PhpUnit that is installed elsewhere